# Is it possible that make PBS to schedule both parallel and serial job on to same node?

Tags: parallel-processing, cluster-computing, schedule, pbs

I am new to cluster and PBS system. I am now wondering this, is it possible to schedule both parallel (MPI, OpenMP) and serial jobs on to one node in a cluster (the cluster has multiple nodes) with PBS system? Because in this way, it may improve the CPU utilization.

I've been told this is not possible but without detailed explanation. So, if this is really impossible, my question is why?

Answer (score 0):

By default, all jobs are candidates to share nodes. In other words, without any configuration to the batch system parallel and serial jobs will share nodes.

Many sites decide to configure things so that this doesn't happen. Common reasons for segregating the jobs include:

1. It is an easy way to set policies for serial and parallel workloads.
2. It minimizes possibilities for one kind of workload to interfere with another.

Comment: Thanks @dbeer. Do you have any reference to your first statement? That is, By default, all jobs are candidates to share nodes. In other words, without any configuration to the batch system parallel and serial jobs will share nodes. I am unable to find this on PBS documents.

Comment: Yes, this is true but it probably isn't explicitly documented.

Comment: Thanks, could you point me to the right configuration file to do so? Is it  /var/spool/pbs/pbs_server.conf or there are any other files I should look at?